# Proving a vector space question

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Having trouble proving this :

$V$ is denoted as vector space

Let $\{\vec {v}_1, \ldots, \vec {v}_n\}$ be a linearly independent set in $V$ and suppose that $\vec {v}_{n+1}$ isn't in  $\operatorname{Span} [\vec {v}_1, \ldots, \vec {v}_n]$. Prove that $\{\vec {v}_1, \ldots, \vec {v}_n,\vec {v}_{n+1}\}$ is also linearly independent,

Comment: [Here's a tutorial in MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Please elaborate on what you've tried so far and where you're stuck. Read [this] (https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) to get a clear idea on how to ask a question to get good response.

Comment: Any thoughts?  Suppose $n=1$...can you do it in that case?

Comment: What's the definition of the span of vectors? What's the definition of linearly independent? Once you have these in hand, this problem should fall quickly.

Answer (score 5):

suppose $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \lambda_i v_i = 0$

if $\lambda_{n+1} = 0$ then all the others must be 0 by linear independence of the first n

otherwise $v_{n+1} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{-\lambda_i}{\lambda_{n+1}} v_i$ which contradicts the statement about it not being in the span

Answer (score 1):

$$
c_1 \vec v_1 + \cdots + c_n \vec v_n + c_{n+1} \vec v_{n+1} = \vec 0
$$
$$
\text{If } c_{n+1} \text{ is not } 0, \text{ then we can divide by it:} \\ \vec v_{n+1} = \frac{- c_1\vec v_1}{c_{n+1}} + \cdots + \frac{-c_n \vec v _n}{c_{n+1}}
$$
But *then* $\vec v_{n+1}$ *is* in the span of $\{\vec v_1,\ldots, \vec v_n\}. $

Thus we conclude that $c_{n+1}$ must be $0$. Therefore we have
$$
c_1 \vec v_1 + \cdots + c_n \vec v_n = \vec 0.
$$
Since $\vec v_1,\ldots,\vec v_n$ are linearly independent, that implies that $c_1=\cdots=c_n=0.$

So we must have $c_1=c_2=\cdots=c_n=c_{n+1}=0.$

Hence $\vec v_1,\ldots, \vec v_{n+1}$ are linearly independent.